# Open text file with self-made program as standard program

Tags: c#, windows

I fear that the title of this question might be unclear, but allow me to clarify it. I wrote a basic text editor in C# with the ability to open and save text files. Now, what I want to achieve is the following:

- Ability to change the standard program that text files (.txt / .rtf) open with to my program.
- Drag text files into my program and let the contents automatically be loaded into the richtextbox.

I'm not sure about the technical terms of something like this, so searching for this question didn't brought me very far. Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: do you want your program to be the default one for .txt and .rtf files?

Comment: search terms "shell extension association" and "drag and drop file C#" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307966)

Answer (score 1):

For Drag & Drop support, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx

To change default programs in Windows, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx